# Don't understand Qt ampersand & bit-wise AND operation: if(ev->buttons() & Qt::RightButton)

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code:

```
void OpenGLRenderer::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    //...

    if(ev->buttons() & Qt::RightButton)
    {
        if(ev->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how ampersand `&` comparisons are working. Is the `&` a bit-wise `AND` operation? How does the statement `ev->buttons() & Qt::RightButton` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behind the return statement of `ev->buttons()`/`ev->modifiers()` and the `Qt::RightButton`/`Qt::ShiftModifier` there is a numeric value.

In order to understand how things work you need to be familiar with `enum`s and in addition to the really neat `QFlags` that allows you to easily combine multiple numeric values (flags) in order to create a complex one.

Let's take a look at the mouse buttons:

```
Qt::NoButton    0x00000000  The button state does not refer to any button (see QMouseEvent::button()).
Qt::LeftButton  0x00000001  The left button is pressed, or an event refers to the left button. (The left button may be the right button on left-handed mice.)
Qt::RightButton 0x00000002  The right button.
Qt::MidButton   0x00000004  The middle button.
Qt::MiddleButton    MidButton   The middle button.
Qt::XButton1    0x00000008  The first X button.
Qt::XButton2    0x00000010  The second X button.
```

You may notice that the values are not sequential and that some are missing. For example where is the 3, or the 5, or the 6 etc.? Let's say you want to handle a situation where both the right and left buttons are pressed.

Behind those numbers (which as hexadecimals) lie simple binary numbers (0s and 1s). If we apply a logical OR to 0x01 and 0x02 we get a 0x03:

```
0x01 | 0x02 = 0x03
```

If we look at those numbers as 0s and 1s we have

```
0x01 (hex) = 01 (bin)
0x02 (hex) = 10 (bin)
0x03 (hex) = 11 (bin)
```

As you can see because of the logical OR we have combined the 1 from the 0x01 and the 1 from the 0x02 into a 11 that is 0x03.

Now lets reverse things and take the 0x03 and see what happens if `ev->buttons()` returns it. If that function returns this result we know that both the 0x01 (left) and 0x02 (right) are currently being pressed. Why? Because there is no other combination from the values from our enumeration that creates a 0x03! If we add the logical AND operator we can rewrite the `if` condition as follows (using only numeric values)

```
if (0x03 & 0x02)
{
  // do something
}
```

But what is the result of `0x03 & 0x02`? It's `0x02` and that is because on the binary level we have

```
     11
AND  10
-------
     10
```

since 1 and 1 is 1 (first column) but 1 and 0 is 0 (second column). If we translate this into a sentence we have "If the right button is currently pressed do ...".

Let's do a more complex case where we have the right, left and middle button (0x01, 0x02 and 0x04) pressed.

```
   001
OR 010
OR 100
------
   111 (bin) = 0x07 (hex) (one of the missing values in the enumeration above!)
```

If we want an `if` statement the body of which is entered only if the right and middle button are pressed we need to do some math (again ;)). First we need to get the value that tells us that both required buttons are pressed:

```
   010 (right button)
OR 100 (middle button)
------
   110 (bin) = 0x06 (hex) (yet another of the missing values in the enumeration above!)
```

Next we need to put that combination against the return statement of the `ev->buttons()`, which in this case returns 0x07 (all of the above three buttons pressed):

```
    110 (Qt::MidButton | Qt::RightButton)
AND 111 (Qt::MidButton | Qt::RightButton | Qt::LeftButton)
-------
    110
```

If we put this in the `if` condition we get

```
if (ev->buttons() & (Qt::MidButton | Qt::RightButton)
{
  // do something
}
```

Clearly if `ev->buttons()` returns something like `Qt::RightButton | Qt::XButton1` (whatever XButton is :D) our `if` condition will fail. Why? Because

```
   0010 (Qt::RightButton)
OR 1000 (Qt::XButton1)
-------
   1010
```

combined with the check for `Qt::MidButton | Qt::RightButton` gives us

```
    1010 (Qt::RightButton | Qt::XButton1)
AND 0110 (Qt::RightButton | Qt::MidButton)
--------
    0010 (Qt::RightButton)
```

The above may seem a little bit strange but all it tells us that the pressed right button is the only thing connecting the two and the X button and mid button are clearly not matching hence our `if` condition will fail.

Now if you want to just check for the right button in both cases you are good to go since

```
    1010 (Qt::RightButton | Qt::XButton1)
AND 0010 (Qt::RightButton)
--------
    0010 (Qt::RightButton)
```

as well as

```
    0110 (Qt::RightButton | Qt::MidButton)
AND 0010 (Qt::RightButton)
--------
    0010 (Qt::RightButton)
```

On the other hand if `ev->buttons()` returns just `Qt::MidButton` but you check for `Qt::RightButton` using the AND operator will get you

```
    0100 (Qt::MidButton)
AND 0010 (Qt::RightButton)
--------
    0000
```

And in terms of logic in C/C++ a numeric value of 0 is the same as the boolean `false` hence the `if`'s body will not be entered.

You can apply the same logic too all flags in Qt.

Comment: Thanks for thoroughness!

Comment: @user3405291 Hope it wasn't too much. :D